# How do I group data using python into multiple groups and assign values?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a function in python in which I can pass a dataframe as the first argument, percent as the second argument and the third argument will be the list of values

Function:

```
foo(df, perc, *args):
```

So, if I call this function like `foo(population_df, 20, 'A','B', 'C')`, then it will add a column to the dataframe and mark first 20 percent of records as A, then next 20 percent of records as B and then next 20 percent of records as C and remaining records as null as we can see in the below images.

Input DF:

[image]

Output DF:

[image]

Similarly, if I pass 12 percent, then it should mark first 12 percent of records as A, next 12 percent of records as B and next 12 percent of records as C and remaining records should be marked as null

Comment: You need to post a code with an issue, not asking recommendation on how to write your code

Comment: Your question and example is imprecise/confusing: you say you want 10% of records to be set to something, but then you only show 5 records, so the bare minimum is 20%. I think being clearer would help.

Comment: Suppose there are 10 records in a table. Than any three random records will be marked as A, B & C. The remaining 7 records will be marked as NULL.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a column to order the dataframe by to differentiate the first 20% from the second 20%, etc, so I added the `ID` column.
I didn't use `percent_rank` transformation; because, its outputs didn't make sense, but if you wanna try it out, `f.percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy(f.col(ordering_column)))` can replace `f.rank().over(Window.orderBy(f.col(ordering_column)))/record_count`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

def func(df, perc, ordering_column, column_values):
    record_count = df.count()
    df = (
        df
        .withColumn('percent_rank', 100*f.rank().over(Window.orderBy(f.col(ordering_column)))/record_count)
        .withColumn('col_values', f.lit(column_values))
        .withColumn('Col', f.element_at(f.col('col_values'), f.round(f.col('percent_rank')/perc).cast('int')))
        .drop('percent_rank', 'col_values')
    )
    
    return df

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'Tom', 'M'),
    (2, 'John', 'M'),
    (3, 'Saily', 'F'),
    (4, 'Noorie', 'F'),
    (5, 'Steve', 'M')
], ['ID', 'Name', 'Gender'])

output = func(df, 20, 'ID', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
output.show()
```

and the output is

```
+---+------+------+----+
| ID|  Name|Gender| Col|
+---+------+------+----+
|  1|   Tom|     M|   A|
|  2|  John|     M|   B|
|  3| Saily|     F|   C|
|  4|Noorie|     F|NULL|
|  5| Steve|     M|NULL|
+---+------+------+----+
```